# Using scroll-behavior: smooth for only one page with CSS

Tags: css

When I enter the code

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

I get the smooth effect that I want for anchor links. However, I only want this effect to apply to a single page, not my whole site. So I thought that perhaps this would work, using the class for the body tag of the single page that I want this effect on.

```
.landing-page {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

However, once I do this the effect doesn't work, even though using the inspect tool shows that this attribute is applied to `.landing-page`. Why isn't it working, and what should I try next?

EDIT:
Here is the HTML. I am trying to have it that I smooth scroll to `#how-it-works` and only that anchor.

```
<body class="landing-page welcome">
<div class="page first">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <a class ="anchor" id="how-it-works"></a>
      <span class="primary-text">
        You have before you the best system for deeply learning math.
      </span>
      <span class="secondary-text">
        Online, real tutors, at your own pace. Ask anything.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have added an answer but if you can add the code then I might be able to assist better.

Comment: Be aware that scroll-behavior: smooth; is not supported by Safari or IE

Comment: You actually picked the answer that not only doesn't explain the cause of your problem properly, it also does unnecessary stuff like adding `overflow: scroll` to the root element. That is not only unnecessary (as explained in my answer, adding the smooth scroll to the root makes the viewport scroll smoothly); using `scroll` instead of `auto` means there's *always* a scroll bar, needed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok one of the issues on your code is that the smooth scroll is not supported by the body tag, try adding a class or an id to your html tag, or just add it on that page inline coded, but it really depends on what restrictions you would have.

```css
html.landing-page {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
 width: 200px;
 marging: auto;
}
```

```html
<html class="landing-page">
<body class="welcome">
<div class="page first">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <a class ="anchor" id="how-it-works"></a>
      <span class="primary-text">
        You have before you the best system for deeply learning math.
      </span>
      <span class="secondary-text">
        Online, real tutors, at your own pace. Ask anything.
        Online, real tutors, at your own pace. Ask anything.
        Online, real tutors, at your own pace. Ask anything.
        Online, real tutors, at your own pace. Ask anything.
        Online, real tutors, at your own pace. Ask anything.
        Online, real tutors, at your own pace. Ask anything.
        
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Another way would be having the code in a div instead of the HTML, but you would have to do some workarounds for it.

```
.landing-page {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh; // test with smaller heights
}
```

Comment: if you give me a bit more code on what your trying that would help also i will add some extra assuming what you have but can change later if you give us more specifics

Comment: try again let me know

Comment: Thanks! Adding a class to the HTML tag worked. I shouldn't have been using it for the body tag.

Comment: The `marging` above should be `margin` but StackOverflow won't let me edit it because "edits must be at least 6 characters". Can you please fix it yourself, Somelight?

Answer (score 3):

> The scroll-behavior CSS property sets the behavior **for a scrolling box** when scrolling is triggered by the navigation or CSSOM scrolling APIs.
> **When this property is specified on the root element, it applies to the viewport instead. *This property specified on the `body` element will not propagate to the viewport*.**

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

So you have two options.

1. Either specify a CSS class like

   .smooth-scroll { scroll-behaviour: smooth; }

and put it on your HTML tag in that specific page (recommended way).

2. Make your body a scrolling element:

   body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow-y: auto;
   }

and place your CSS class on the body for that page.