# How do you animate going to another section in HTML

Tags: javascript, css

Soo my question here is for the code here:

```
<a href="#section">Click Here</a>


(imagine theres lots of things here)

<h1 id="section"> HERE! </h1>
```

Once I click the a tag, how do I animate going to that section? Like I'm scrolling down?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: This is helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824331/104380

Answer (score 0):

in your css you can do:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```